# How to calculate startDate(UTC) with endDate( ISO8601 and durationDays

Tags: python

I have endDate with ISO8601 format and durationDays now.
And I want to calculate the startDate with UTC format
I not sure whether my code is right :
when I get
`datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(startDate_Timestamp)`
it's like `2015-09-26 05:08:23` without timezone
So I add one . But I not sure is it correctly ??

```
import datetime
import dateutil.tz
import dateutil.parser
import time
import pytz


endDate = "2015-10-10T01:08:03-04:00"
durationDays = 13.666435185185186

#convert endDate from ISO8601 to UTC time
pyTime =  dateutil.parser.parse(endDate)
endDateUTC =  pyTime.astimezone(dateutil.tz.tzutc())
print endDateUTC

#convert pyTimeUTC to Timestamp
pyTimeUTC_Timestamp = time.mktime(endDateUTC.timetuple())
print pyTimeUTC_Timestamp


# durationDays * 24 * 60 * 60
durationtimes = durationDays* 24 * 60 * 60

#get startdate Timestamp
startDate_Timestamp = pyTimeUTC_Timestamp - durationtimes
print startDate_Timestamp

# convert startDate_Timestamp back to UTC time
startDateUTC = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(startDate_Timestamp).replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
print startDateUTC
```

Comment: what issue are you getting? You will need to be specific

Comment: BTW , how did you come up with the `durationDays = 13.666435185185186` , did you manually calculate it from some 13 days 16 hours some other minutes/seconds ?

Comment: ````durationDays```` value is from kickstarter website

Answer (score 0):

You can test it like this to see if it's giving the dates you want:

```
(endDateUTC-startDateUTC).days
13
(endDateUTC-startDateUTC).seconds
28780
```